# How to call an m file from another m file in MATLAB and retrieve an output?

Tags: file, matlab, function

I know this is a simple question, but for some reason I can't find a straight answer that works no matter where I look.

Basically, I have 4 values that were found in one m file, and I want to run them through a separate m file and retrieve the output from it.

I tried something like these, but none worked:

```
result = generate(nrow,ncol,a,b);
function result = generate(nrow,ncol,a,b);
result = @generate(nrow,ncol,a,b);
```

The final value in the m file "generate" is called `result`, and I'm trying to carry that across to my initial m file.

Any advice as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated! Please and thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. if your file `generate.m` defines a  function it should have itself the following structure (which takes into account the fact that you have four returned values)

   ```
   function [ret1 ret2 ret3 ret4] = generate(nrow,ncol,a,b)

         ....             % # Some processing of yours

         ret1 = ... ;     % # Returned values are eventually set
         ret2 = ... ;
         ret3 = ... ;
         ret4 = ... ;
   end
   ```
2. The function should be called (e.g. in your *main* script) as

   ```
   [ret1 ret2 ret3 ret4] = generate(nrow,ncol,a,b);
   ```

   now you have the variables `ret1,ret2,ret3,ret4` available in the caller scope.

   Be aware that the file `generate.m` must be in the current matlab [PATH](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/path.html).